# Error al abrir una ventana desde otra en QMainWindow

Tags: python, pyqt5

Estoy tratando de abrir una venta diferente desde mi ventana principal, esto al terminar de ejecutarse la funcion `obetenerHostNmae()`.

Para lo cual hago una instancia de la clase `CInicial()` y la mando a llamar con el metodo `show()` sin embargo al hacer esto el programa se queda trabado y no hace nada mas:

Trate de hacerlo pero con la clase `Contenedor()` ya que pense que esa seria la clase ala que habria que llamar pero tampoco funciono:

Esto intente con `contenedor()`

`Contenedor(CInical).show()` **No funciono**

archivo1.py

```
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QMainWindow,QApplication,QMessageBox
from PyQt5.QtCore import Qt,QTimer
from PyQt5 import uic,QtCore
import socket
import threading
from threading import Timer
import keyboard
from ConfigInicial import CInicial,Contenedor

class Hilo(threading.Thread):
    def __init__(self,obj):
        threading.Thread.__init__(self)
        #self.text = text
        self.obj = obj

    def run(self):
        Inicio.onError(self.obj,"Error", "errrrrror")
        #QtCore.QMetaObject.invokeMethod(self.obj,'onError',
        #   QtCore.Qt.QueuedConnection,
        #   QtCore.Q_ARG(str,"Error"),
        #   QtCore.Q_ARG(str,'errorr'))

class Inicio(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        QMainWindow.__init__(self)
        uic.loadUi("Inicio.ui",self)

        self.timer = QTimer()

        #Instancia de clases
        self.Next1 = CInicial()

        keyboard.add_hotkey('ctrl+s', lambda:Hilo(self).start())

        self.setWindowFlags(Qt.FramelessWindowHint)

        self.Lstatus.setText("Obteniendo Host...")
        t = Timer(2, self.obetenerHostNmae)
        t.start()

    #@QtCore.pyqtSlot(str,str)
    def onError(self,title,text):
        QMessageBox.critical(None,title,text,QMessageBox.Ok)
    def obetenerHostNmae(self):

        solved = socket.gethostname()
        self.Lstatus.setText(solved)
        self.close()
        self.Next1.show()




app = QApplication([])
i = Inicio()
i.show()
app.exec_()
```

archivo2.py

```
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QMainWindow,QWidget,QVBoxLayout,QApplication,QGraphicsDropShadowEffect
from PyQt5 import QtCore,QtGui
from PyQt5.QtGui import QPainter,QColor
from PyQt5 import uic


class Contenedor(QWidget):
    def __init__(self,window):
        QWidget.__init__(self)

        #self.setWindowFlags(QtCore.Qt.FramelessWindowHint)
        #self.setAttribute(QtCore.Qt.WA_TranslucentBackground)

        lay = QVBoxLayout(self)
        lay.addWidget(window)
        #lay.setContentsMargins(10,10,10,10)

        shadow = QGraphicsDropShadowEffect(self)
        shadow.setBlurRadius(9.9)
        shadow.setColor(QColor(95,99,114))
        shadow.setOffset(8,8)

        #window.setGraphicsEffect(shadow)

class CInicial(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        QMainWindow.__init__(self)
        #uic.loadUi("ConfiguracionInicial.ui",self)



app = QApplication([])
w = CInicial()
contenedor = Contenedor(w)
contenedor.resize(640,480)
contenedor.show()
app.exec_()
```

inicio.ui

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ui version="4.0">
 <class>MainWindow</class>
 <widget class="QMainWindow" name="MainWindow">
  <property name="geometry">
   <rect>
    <x>0</x>
    <y>0</y>
    <width>683</width>
    <height>482</height>
   </rect>
  </property>
  <property name="windowTitle">
   <string>MainWindow</string>
  </property>
  <property name="styleSheet">
   <string notr="true"/>
  </property>
  <widget class="QWidget" name="centralwidget">
   <property name="styleSheet">
    <string notr="true"/>
   </property>
   <widget class="QFrame" name="frame">
    <property name="geometry">
     <rect>
      <x>200</x>
      <y>-1</y>
      <width>485</width>
      <height>484</height>
     </rect>
    </property>
    <property name="styleSheet">
     <string notr="true">background:url(SD.jpg)</string>
    </property>
    <property name="frameShape">
     <enum>QFrame::StyledPanel</enum>
    </property>
    <property name="frameShadow">
     <enum>QFrame::Raised</enum>
    </property>
    <widget class="QFrame" name="frame_4">
     <property name="geometry">
      <rect>
       <x>0</x>
       <y>462</y>
       <width>681</width>
       <height>20</height>
      </rect>
     </property>
     <property name="styleSheet">
      <string notr="true">background:none;
border:0px;
border-bottom:3px solid qlineargradient(spread:pad, x1:0, y1:0, x2:1, y2:0, stop:0 rgba(54, 77, 185, 244), stop:1 rgba(42, 46, 48, 255));</string>
     </property>
     <property name="frameShape">
      <enum>QFrame::StyledPanel</enum>
     </property>
     <property name="frameShadow">
      <enum>QFrame::Raised</enum>
     </property>
    </widget>
   </widget>
   <widget class="QFrame" name="frame_2">
    <property name="geometry">
     <rect>
      <x>0</x>
      <y>0</y>
      <width>201</width>
      <height>491</height>
     </rect>
    </property>
    <property name="styleSheet">
     <string notr="true">QFrame#frame_2{
background:#2a2e30;

}</string>
    </property>
    <property name="frameShape">
     <enum>QFrame::StyledPanel</enum>
    </property>
    <property name="frameShadow">
     <enum>QFrame::Raised</enum>
    </property>
    <widget class="QLabel" name="label">
     <property name="geometry">
      <rect>
       <x>20</x>
       <y>130</y>
       <width>161</width>
       <height>21</height>
      </rect>
     </property>
     <property name="font">
      <font>
       <pointsize>11</pointsize>
       <weight>75</weight>
       <bold>true</bold>
      </font>
     </property>
     <property name="styleSheet">
      <string notr="true">

color:#4057A3;
color:#4253f4;</string>
     </property>
     <property name="text">
      <string>School Admin</string>
     </property>
     <property name="alignment">
      <set>Qt::AlignLeading|Qt::AlignLeft|Qt::AlignVCenter</set>
     </property>
    </widget>
    <widget class="QLabel" name="label_2">
     <property name="geometry">
      <rect>
       <x>20</x>
       <y>40</y>
       <width>70</width>
       <height>70</height>
      </rect>
     </property>
     <property name="text">
      <string/>
     </property>
     <property name="pixmap">
      <pixmap>asd.png</pixmap>
     </property>
     <property name="scaledContents">
      <bool>true</bool>
     </property>
    </widget>
    <widget class="QLabel" name="label_3">
     <property name="geometry">
      <rect>
       <x>4</x>
       <y>464</y>
       <width>131</width>
       <height>16</height>
      </rect>
     </property>
     <property name="styleSheet">
      <string notr="true">color:#4253F4;</string>
     </property>
     <property name="text">
      <string>School Admin - v.0.0.1</string>
     </property>
    </widget>
    <widget class="QLabel" name="label_4">
     <property name="geometry">
      <rect>
       <x>20</x>
       <y>150</y>
       <width>161</width>
       <height>31</height>
      </rect>
     </property>
     <property name="font">
      <font>
       <pointsize>8</pointsize>
      </font>
     </property>
     <property name="styleSheet">
      <string notr="true">color:#4253F4;</string>
     </property>
     <property name="text">
      <string>School administration system</string>
     </property>
    </widget>
    <widget class="QLabel" name="label_5">
     <property name="geometry">
      <rect>
       <x>20</x>
       <y>190</y>
       <width>131</width>
       <height>16</height>
      </rect>
     </property>
     <property name="font">
      <font>
       <pointsize>8</pointsize>
       <weight>75</weight>
       <bold>true</bold>
      </font>
     </property>
     <property name="styleSheet">
      <string notr="true">QLabel#label_5{
color:#4253F4;
background:none;
border:none;

}</string>
     </property>
     <property name="text">
      <string>Director's version</string>
     </property>
     <property name="alignment">
      <set>Qt::AlignLeading|Qt::AlignLeft|Qt::AlignVCenter</set>
     </property>
    </widget>
    <widget class="QLabel" name="statusInicio">
     <property name="geometry">
      <rect>
       <x>20</x>
       <y>250</y>
       <width>161</width>
       <height>31</height>
      </rect>
     </property>
     <property name="font">
      <font>
       <pointsize>8</pointsize>
      </font>
     </property>
     <property name="styleSheet">
      <string notr="true">color:#4253F4;</string>
     </property>
     <property name="text">
      <string/>
     </property>
    </widget>
    <widget class="QLabel" name="Lstatus">
     <property name="geometry">
      <rect>
       <x>20</x>
       <y>230</y>
       <width>161</width>
       <height>31</height>
      </rect>
     </property>
     <property name="font">
      <font>
       <pointsize>8</pointsize>
      </font>
     </property>
     <property name="styleSheet">
      <string notr="true">color:#4253F4;</string>
     </property>
     <property name="text">
      <string/>
     </property>
    </widget>
   </widget>
   <zorder>frame_2</zorder>
   <zorder>frame</zorder>
  </widget>
 </widget>
 <resources/>
 <connections/>
</ui>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Te recomiendo usar `if __name__ == '__main__':` si vas a testear cada parte de tu proyecto ya que si no lo usas vas a ejecutar el codigo que esta fuera de las clases y funciones que te podria generar problemas, por ejemplo estas creando un QApplication en cada archivo, osea tiene 2 QApplication que Qt prohibe.

Por otro lado como veo que quieres usar el Contenedor junto a CInicial es mejor crear una función que retorne ambos elementos y que implemente la funcionalidad de añadir uno a otro:

**ConfigInicial.py**

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets 

class Contenedor(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    def __init__(self, window, parent=None):
        super(Contenedor, self).__init__(parent)
        self.setWindowFlags(QtCore.Qt.FramelessWindowHint)
        self.setAttribute(QtCore.Qt.WA_TranslucentBackground)
        lay = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(self)
        lay.addWidget(window)
        lay.setContentsMargins(10,10,10,10)

        shadow = QtWidgets.QGraphicsDropShadowEffect(self,
            blurRadius=9.9,
            color=QtGui.QColor(95,99,114),
            offset = QtCore.QPoint(8,8))
        window.setGraphicsEffect(shadow)

class CInicial(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(CInicial, self).__init__(parent)
        # test
        self.setCentralWidget(QtWidgets.QTextEdit())

def crear_ventana():
    inicial = CInicial()
    contenedor =Contenedor(inicial)
    contenedor.resize(640, 480)
    return contenedor, inicial

if __name__ == '__main__':
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication([])
    w = CInicial()
    contenedor = Contenedor(w)
    contenedor.resize(640,480)
    contenedor.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Entonces ahora solo debes llamar esa funcion y obtener los objetos que deseas. Por otro lado veo innecesario usar el objeto Timer ya que Qt provee el método estático `QTimer.singleShot(...)`, he eliminado lo del hilo porque para el ejemplo es irrelevante.

```
import socket
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtWidgets, uic

import ConfigInicial

class Inicio(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(Inicio, self).__init__(parent)
        uic.loadUi("Inicio.ui",self)
        self.setWindowFlags(QtCore.Qt.FramelessWindowHint)
        self.Lstatus.setText("Obteniendo Host...")
        QtCore.QTimer.singleShot(2000, self.obtener_hostname)
        self.next, _ = ConfigInicial.crear_ventana()

    def obtener_hostname(self):
        solved = socket.gethostname()
        self.Lstatus.setText(solved)
        self.close()
        self.next.show()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    i = Inicio()
    i.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Answer (score 0):

Creo que debes instanciar la clase completa, yo haria una funcion que la mande llamar (obviamente antes importando la clase)

```
def llamar_segunda_ventana(self):
    self.segunda_ventana=Inicio()
    self.segunda_ventana.show()
```

Y agregaria la funcion a un boton